# Jetpack Compose Adding Elements Top of The List Instead of ReversedLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to adding my String elements top of the list. I know I can use Lazy Column's reversedlayout way.

```
    var cont by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    var conts by remember {
        mutableStateOf(listOf<String>())
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier= Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = cont,
                onValueChange = { text ->
                    cont = text
                })
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    if (cont.isNotBlank()) {
                        conts = conts + cont
                        cont = ""
                    }
                }

            ) {
                Text(text = "Add")
            }

        }
        Spacer(modifier= Modifier.height(10.dp))
        LazyColumn(reverseLayout = true){
            items(conts){ currentcont->
                Text(text = currentcont)
            }
        }
    }
```

In this case I can display in reverse order thanks to reverseLayout.

I tried to removing this thing.
In 'if block' if I try to change of adding code to `conts=cont+conts` it gives type mismatch error because conts expects string type of list and it makes sense but couldn't find any other way.

I wonder is there any basic level method to adding top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to run:

```
conts = cont + conts
```

it fails because you can't concatenate a String with a list. There's no method `plus(List)` in the String class. However, there is a method `plus(String)` in the List class, so that's why the following code was correct:

```
conts = conts + cont
```

In order to add an element to the beginning of a [immutable] list, you can try the following:

```
conts = listOf(cont) + conts
```

Now you create a list with only one element (`cont`), and then you concatenate that list to another list (`const`), which is what you expect.

Comment: I understood the plus method, I appreciate it.

But I have a new question for this new way to linking list have only one element. 
Will new and lots of lists cause more memory usage or will be same as old way?